# How do these alternative Q# algorithms produce the same set of Bell states?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, q#

In the "Superposition" Microsoft quantum katas (https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Superposition/ReferenceImplementation.qs) the solution for Task 7 looks like this:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------
// Task 7. All Bell states
// Inputs:
//      1) two qubits in |00⟩ state (stored in an array of length 2)
//      2) an integer index
// Goal: create one of the Bell states based on the value of index:
//       0: |Φ⁺⟩ = (|00⟩ + |11⟩) / sqrt(2)
//       1: |Φ⁻⟩ = (|00⟩ - |11⟩) / sqrt(2)
//       2: |Ψ⁺⟩ = (|01⟩ + |10⟩) / sqrt(2)
//       3: |Ψ⁻⟩ = (|01⟩ - |10⟩) / sqrt(2)

operation AllBellStates_Reference (qs : Qubit[], index : Int) : Unit is Adj {
H(qs[0]);
CNOT(qs[0], qs[1]);

// now we have |00⟩ + |11⟩ - modify it based on index arg
if (index % 2 == 1) {
    // negative phase
    Z(qs[1]);
}
if (index / 2 == 1) {
    X(qs[1]);
}
```

}

---

And my alternative solution looks like this:

```
// Task 7. All Bell states 
// Inputs: 
//      1) two qubits in |00⟩ state (stored in an array of length 2) 
//      2) an integer index 
// Goal: create one of the Bell states based on the value of index: 
//    0: |Φ⁺⟩ = (|00⟩ + |11⟩) / sqrt(2) 
//    1: |Φ⁻⟩ = (|00⟩ - |11⟩) / sqrt(2) 
//    2: |Ψ⁺⟩ = (|01⟩ + |10⟩) / sqrt(2) 
//    3: |Ψ⁻⟩ = (|01⟩ - |10⟩) / sqrt(2)

operation AllBellStates (qs : Qubit[], index : Int) : Unit 
{
H(qs[0]);
CNOT(qs[0], qs[1]);

if (index == 0){ 
} elif(index == 1) {
    Z(qs[0]);
} elif(index == 2){
    X(qs[0]);
} elif(index == 3){
    X(qs[0]);
    Z(qs[1]);
}
```

}

---

**Yet BOTH solutions pass the unit tests**. How is that possible, since the X-gate and Z-gate operators are being applied to the **other** qubit in the pair?
Could the unit test logic be incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit test logic is correct, no worries there! One of the really neat things about the four Bell states is that you can transform between each using single-qubit operations.
For example, consider the Bell state $\left|\Phi^{+}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\left|00\right\rangle + \left|11\right\rangle\right)$. Flipping the first qubit with an `X` instruction transforms the state of your qubits to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\left|10\right\rangle + \left|01\right\rangle\right)$, while flipping the second qubit with `X(qs[1])` transforms your qubits into the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\left|01\right\rangle + \left|10\right\rangle\right)$. Since addition is commutative (that is, $a + b = b + a$), these two states are equal.

Thus, even though `X(qs[0])` and `X(qs[1])` are very different instructions, they do the same thing in the special case of the Bell state $\left|\Phi^{+}\right\rangle$.
In the same way, `Z(qs[0])` and `Z(qs[1])` do the same thing to $\left|\Phi^{+}\right\rangle$.
Another way of thinking of why this is is that the quantum programs `ApplyToEach(X, qs)` and `ApplyToEach(Z, qs)` do *nothing* to qubits in the state $\left|\Phi^{+}\right\rangle$, similarly to how `Z(q)` does nothing when `q` is in the state |0⟩.
If you're interested, there's a beautiful mathematical framework known as the *stabilizer formalism* for helping to track these kinds of symmetries of quantum states.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation.